# Deleting youngest student's row in each group of ListView control

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I filled this data in a multi-column ListView1 of my C# app:

Student | DOB | Location

Student -  DOB - Location

Group1
AAA - 10-05-2000 - New York
BBB - 05-02-2000 - San Francisco
CCC - 01-01-2000 - Washington

Group2
DDD - 20-03-1999 - Chicago
EEE - 15-06-1999 - New York
FFF - 18-09-1999 - Houstan

I spent 4 hours, tried below code with no luck.

```
IEnumerable<Student> earlydatestudents = Students.GroupBy(std => std.Group)
    .Select(grp =>
    {
        DateTime dt = grp.Min(s => s.DOB);
        return grp.Where(st => st.DOB == dt);
    })
    .SelectMany(slist => slist);

var toDeleteList = Students.Except(earlydatestudents).ToList();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with the code above? At first glance it seems to do what is expected. Create a list of the youngest students in each group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working.  It's not very clear what you want to delete. In the title it states to delete the youngest, but `toDeleteList` contains all students except the youngest.

This is how you can get only one the youngest student from each group:

```
var toDeleteList = students.GroupBy(x => x.DOB.Year)   
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.DOB).Take(1))
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Here you get all the youngest students from each group (if some of them have the same ealiest DOB):

```
var toDeleteList = students.GroupBy(x => x.DOB.Year)
    .Select(g => g.Where(x => x.DOB == g.Min(gr => gr.DOB)))
    .SelectMany(x => x);
    .ToList();
```

`GroupBy(x => x.DOB.Year)` groups students into two groups as I noticed that all students from `Group1` has 2000 year and all students from `Group2` have 1999 year of DOB. I did it just to get two groups of students to match your example. Of course, you should group as you like.